# r wrong to parse json

Tags: r, json

I just started to study r. Here is my json file.

```
'[
 {
  "Ua_edr": 14040061,
   "Education_name": "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Short_name": "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Teacher_Name": "Левенць Наталія Іванівна",
   "Sex": "жін.",
   "Status": "вчитель математики",
   "Years_practice": 46,
   "Position": "директор",
   "Category": "вища"
 },
 {
  "Ua_edr": 14040061,
  "Education_name": "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
  "Short_name": "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
  "Teacher_Name": "Кулянда Оксана Сергіївна",
  "Sex": "жін.",
  "Status": "вчитель української мови та літератури",
  "Years_practice": 29,
  "Position": "заступник директора з навчально-виховної роботи",
  "Category": "вища"
},
{
  "Ua_edr": 14040061,
  "Education_name": "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
  "Short_name": "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
  "Teacher_Name": "Семчук Андрій  Ярославович",
  "Sex": "чол.",
  "Status": "вчитель математики, інформатики та обчислювальної техніки",
  "Years_practice": 21,
  "Position": "заступник директора з навчально-виховної роботи",
  "Category": "вища"
 },
{
  "Ua_edr": 14040061,
  "Education_name": "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
  "Short_name": "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
  "Teacher_Name": "Федоруц Микола Васильович",
  "Sex": "чол.",
  "Status": "вчитель основ географії, основ економіки, природознавства, організатор краєзнавчо-туристичної роботи",
  "Years_practice": 7,
  "Position": "заступник директора з виховної роботи",
  "Category": "друга"
},
{
 "Ua_edr": 14040061,
 "Education_name": "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
 "Short_name": "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
 "Teacher_Name": "Ляврін Інна Іванівна",
  "Sex": "жін.",
  "Status": "вчитель біології",


"Years_practice": 3,
   "Position": "педагог-організатор",
   "Category": "спеціаліст"
 },
 {



"Ua_edr": 14040061,
   "Education_name": "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Short_name": "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Teacher_Name": "Андрунько Лілія Ігорівна",
   "Sex": "жін.",
   "Status": "вчитель початкових класів та народознавства",
   "Years_practice": 14,
   "Position": "вчитель",
   "Category": "перша"
 },
 {
   "Ua_edr": 14040061,
   "Education_name": "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Short_name": "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Teacher_Name": "Баб'як Наталія Іванівна",
   "Sex": "жін.",
   "Status": "вчитель з інформатики",
   "Years_practice": 9,
   "Position": "вчитель",
   "Category": "друга"
 },
 {
   "Ua_edr": 14040061,
   "Education_name": "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Short_name": "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Teacher_Name": "Бакалець Ганна Миронівна",
   "Sex": "жін.",
   "Status": "вчитель з основ здоров'я",
   "Years_practice": 2,
   "Position": "вчитель",
   "Category": "спеціаліст"
 },
 {
   "Ua_edr": 14040061,
   "Education_name": "Тернопільська загальноосвітня школа І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Short_name": "ТЗОШ І-ІІІ ступенів №4",
   "Teacher_Name": "Бабіна Марія Олександрівна",
   "Sex": "жін.",
   "Status": "вчитель української мови та літератури, зарубіжної літератури, російської мови та літератури",
   "Years_practice": 7,
   "Position": "вчитель",
   "Category": "спеціаліст"
 }
]
```

My code is to import this file into r.

```
library(RJSONIO)
ped4<-fromJSON(file = "e:/DEP/Gol/Ped4.json")
json_ped4<-as.data.frame(ped4)
```

As a result, the fields are duplicated

```
> names(json_ped4)
  [1] "Ua_edr"            "Education_name"    "Short_name"        "Teacher_Name"      "Sex"              
  [6] "Status"            "Years_practice"    "Position"          "Category"          "Ua_edr.1"         
 [11] "Education_name.1"  "Short_name.1"      "Teacher_Name.1"    "Sex.1"             "Status.1"         
 [16] "Years_practice.1"  "Position.1"        "Category.1"        "Ua_edr.2"          "Education_name.2" 
 [21] "Short_name.2"      "Teacher_Name.2"    "Sex.2"             "Status.2"          "Years_practice.2" 
 [26] "Position.2"        "Category.2"        "Ua_edr.3"          "Education_name.3"  "Short_name.3"     
 [31] "Teacher_Name.3"    "Sex.3"             "Status.3"          "Years_practice.3"  "Position.3"       
 [36] "Category.3"        "Ua_edr.4"          "Education_name.4"  "Short_name.4"      "Teacher_Name.4"   
 [41] "Sex.4"             "Status.4"          "Years_practice.4"  "Position.4"        "Category.4"
```

How do I make the fields in one instance (and not Ua_edr, Ua_edr1, Ua_edr2, ....... Ua_edr4)?
Here are the screens:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JQTh.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2wiz.png)
Help please!!!

Comment: not sure if this is an option for you but I don't have this issue when using the `jsonlite` package. For me `ped4<-fromJSON(txt = "e:/DEP/Gol/Ped4.json")` works (provided you load the `jsonlite` package instead of `RJSONIO`).

Comment: Just tried jsonlite package. 
The same.

Comment: are you sure you loaded the `jsonlite` package and did not load the `RJSONIO` package afterwards (otherwise the `RJSONIO` function will still be used since they have the same name). You may have to restart your R session before trying.

Comment: Also the single quote at the beginning of your JSON file caused problems for me so I removed it.

Comment: THANKS!!!!
Can you immediately tell where to read about parsing complex json files? When there are several entries in one entry.

Comment: do you mean these nested columns you will get? I'm not sure there is a good solution. using the dplyr's `mutate()` in conjunction with `rowwise()` may help you. There is also this great package which may help you: https://github.com/sailthru/tidyjson